# is it possible to report on the history records of a custom object?

Tags: reporting, administration, configuration, custom-report-type

---

I created a custom object and set history tracking on one of the fields for the object, I added the history to the page layout for the object. For any particular record for that object I can now see when that field changes. I now want to be able to report on when the field changes. I cannot find a history report for the custom object and I cannot create a report type that shows the history records for the object. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create an object with both `Allow Reports` and `Track Field History` checked and track at least one field then a report type called `[Object Name] Field History` should be automatically generated in the `Other Reports` folder.

You cannot create custom Report Types that use the `[Object Name] Field History` object unfortunately.

It should also be noted that reporting on field history tracking of a custom object is not available if the object is a detail of a Master-Detail Relationship. This is covered in this [Knowledge Article (#000003727)](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003727&language=en_US).

Comment: Note that this will not work in the object is the Detail of a Master-Detail relationship : https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gu7cAAA