# How would I make a lead with lead history report?

Tags: custom-report-type, custom-reports

How do you make a lead with lead history custom report?

I tried making the report type only to find that lead history isn't one of the possible secondary objects.

Since lead history is a related list to the lead object once the field tracking history is setup, shouldn't it be an available option to select as a secondary object when creating a custom report type with Lead as the primary object?

Similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41027/is-it-possible-to-report-on-the-history-records-of-a-custom-object?rq=1) question, but the standard lead object rather than a custom object is what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run reports on the History objects by themselves, e.g. Lead History, Contact History, etc.  You can't combine the history object with anything else.

Comment: right, I've had to use Data Loader Export or similar such tool to do the SOQL

Comment: That's what I thought too until I saw I had this report type from installed packages. https://postimg.cc/VSx15nd7. Aren't those report types what we're saying is not possible?

Comment: I presume you've verified that these custom report types pull from the actual LeadHistory object and not from something else?  Have you asked the package vendor how they built these report types?

Comment: I haven't asked them no. But before I do that, could you tell me where I could actually check which object they're pulling from? There's nothing visible in the "custom report types" settings page. Where else could I check?

Comment: Since they built the report type, they'll have to tell you the object they're using.